# How to convert wav to mp3 using pure java?

Tags: java

How can i use an api java for converting wav files to mp3 files without installing anything ? I tried JMF but it need to install JMStudio, and the broblem is that i need to not install anything. Who can give me an advice about something pure java !

Answer (score 2):

You can't, without writing your own MP3 encoder. The MP3 format is patent encumbered, so the JRE cannot ship with a codec for it.

Comment: Can you explain more about how could i writ my own MP3 encoder and how match time needed, thank you